# create list with value from ldap oracle apex

Tags: oracle, list, function, ldap, apex

i would like to create a list with data from ldap directory.
I want to be able to display this list and go through this list to select a user from the list.

I have already read about pipeline functions that can return a list (can I as well retrieve data from ldap with such a function?). Another function can then be used to start a search through the list.
I haven't had much to do with ldap so far and would be grateful for any hints and yes in our system we use ldap for authentication.

---

1. create object type:

create or replace type ldap_user_ot as object
(email varchar2(30),
username varchar2(30),
firstname varchar2(256),
lastname varchar2(256),
uuid number);

2. create nested table type:

   create or replace type ldap_user_nt as table of ldap_user_ot;
3. create table function

   create or replace function get_user_from_ldap (
   p_container IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',ou=users,dc=my-company,dc=en')---what to enter here???

   ```
        return ldap_user_nt
        PIPELINED

        IS 

        l_retval          PLS_INTEGER;
        l_session         dbms_ldap.SESSION;
        l_attrs           dbms_ldap.string_collection;
        l_message         dbms_ldap.message;
        l_entry           dbms_ldap.message;
        l_attr_name       VARCHAR2(256);
        l_ber_element     dbms_ldap.ber_element;
        l_vals            dbms_ldap.string_collection;
        l_user            ldap_user_ot:=ldap_user_ot(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

        begin
        --IF p_ad_group IS NOT NULL THEN  lv_retval := -1; ----what to enter here? do I need if statement since I want to return all users
        -- Choose to raise exceptions.
              dbms_ldap.use_exception := TRUE;
        -- Connect to the LDAP server.
              l_session := dbms_ldap.Init(hostname => l_ldap_host,
                           portnum => l_ldap_port)
              ;
              l_retval := dbms_ldap.Simple_bind_s(ld => l_session, dn => v_un,
                          passwd => p_password);
               -- Get all attributes
              l_attrs(1) := '*'; 


         l_retval := dbms_ldap.Search_s(ld => l_session, base => l_ldap_base, scope
                          =>
                                      dbms_ldap.scope_subtree,
                          filter => '(&(objectclass=posixAccount)(uid='
                          ||p_user_name
                          ||'))', attrs => l_attrs, attronly => 0, res => l_message);
         IF dbms_ldap.Count_entries(ld => l_session, msg => l_message) > 0 THEN
                v_tableresult := 1;
           -- Get all the entries returned by our search.
                l_entry := dbms_ldap.First_entry(ld => l_session, msg => l_message);    
         << entry_loop >>
                WHILE l_entry IS NOT NULL LOOP
                    -- Get all the attributes for this entry.
                    dbms_output.Put_line('---------------------------------------');

                    l_attr_name := dbms_ldap.First_attribute(ld => l_session,
                                   ldapentry => l_entry,
                                                  ber_elem => l_ber_element);

                    << attributes_loop >>
                    WHILE l_attr_name IS NOT NULL LOOP
                        -- Get all the values for this attribute.
                        l_vals := dbms_ldap.Get_values (ld => l_session,
                                  ldapentry => l_entry,
                                  attr
                                  =>
                                  l_attr_name
                                  );

                        << values_loop >>
                        FOR i IN l_vals.first .. l_vals.last LOOP
                            CASE l_attr_name
                              WHEN 'mail' THEN
                                v_email := Substr(L_vals(i), 1, 200);
                              WHEN 'givenName' THEN
                                v_firstname := Substr(L_vals(i), 1, 200);
                              WHEN 'uid' THEN
                                v_username := Substr(L_vals(i), 1, 200);
                              WHEN 'sn' THEN
                                v_lastname := Substr(L_vals(i), 1, 200);

                              ELSE
                                dbms_output.Put_line('ATTIBUTE_NAME: '
                                                     || l_attr_name
                                                     || ' = '
                                                     || Substr(L_vals(i), 1, 200));
                            END CASE;
                        END LOOP values_loop;  
                         l_attr_name := dbms_ldap.Next_attribute(ld => l_session,
                                       ldapentry => l_entry,
                                                      ber_elem => l_ber_element);
                    END LOOP attibutes_loop;

                    l_entry := dbms_ldap.Next_entry(ld => l_session, msg => l_entry);
              PIPE ROW(l_user); 
                END LOOP entry_loop;
              END IF;

              l_retval := dbms_ldap.Unbind_s(ld => l_session);
              end if;
              return;

              EXCEPTION    WHEN no_data_needed THEN      
              -- unbind from the directory       
               l_retval := dbms_ldap.Unbind_s(ld => l_session);
               return;
                WHEN others THEN     
                 IF l_session IS NOT NULL THEN        
                 l_retval := dbms_ldap.Unbind_s(ld => l_session);    
                 END IF;     
                  RAISE;  
                  END get_user_from_ldap;
   ```

Comment: Oracle-base has a good article on how to use DBMS_LDAP: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ldap-from-plsql-9i

Comment: OK.  What, exactly, is your code not doing that you want it to do (or doing that you don't want it to)?  I'm assuming that since you modeled it after Tim's code that it is querying LDAP correctly.  If you want to modify data in the database, you really want your code to be in a stored procedure not a stored function.  Other than that, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I want to create a list with all email addresses from the directory.
I would then like to call up this list in a page element. In other words, the user can select a person from the list that is fed from the directory. 
When a person has been selected, I want to check if this person exists  the USERS table, if the person is not, I want to make an entry in the table USERS with the required data from the directory.

Comment: I changed the question, since I think this implementation would make more sense.

Comment: So what I am actually trying to do is: Make a PL/SQL PIPELINED function that queries my LDAP with DBMS_LDAP and returns a table of emails. Then define a SQL-Query to  use it in LOV for the page item.